# What is the meaning of region momentum (or dual momenta) variables in the worldsheet?

Tags: momentum, string-theory, conformal-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, correlation-functions

In scattering amplitudes, we deal with usual momentum variables which flow across any edge in a Feynman diagram. For a colour ordered amplitude, we can further designate region momenta to the planes in between edges of a Feynman diagram. How to interpret these momenta? Should these be thought of as a re-definition of the usual momenta in the sense that the difference of two region momenta is the usual momenta on a particular line/edge? Or is there any better explanation of such momentum variables from string theory perspective?